# Android's ToggleButton setChecked(...) method not changing status of button

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have a togglebutton which is not responding to my setChecked(...) method. Here is the code:

```
mBool = mPrefs.getBoolean("buttondefault", true);
Boolean b = mBool; //Only creating this for Logging, mBool IS PRIMITIVE
Log.e("Update pref", b.toString());
mToggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ac_toggle);
mToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
mToggle.setChecked(mBool);
```

The log reports mBool to be **true**, let when I do `mToggle.setChecked(mBool)` the button remains in the off position.

Here is the xml for the button:

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ac_toggle"
android:textOn="Yes"
android:textOff="No"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
android:layout_weight="5"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put this code inside onCreate() ?

Comment: Yes, this code is called in onCreate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code I presented was just copied from different methods. Long story short I was setting the boolean after I initialized and set the button's checked status. Apologies.

Comment: Answer to own question and logical mistake

Answer (score 5):

Please use primitive boolean to set the state

```
//set true or false based on your prefs
boolean mBool = true;
mToggle.setChecked(mBool);
```

Comment: I commented in code that i was only creating a Boolean (nonprimitive) because i wanted to use its toString() method for logging. The boolean I am using for setChecked() is primitive.

Comment: This is obviously a bit late, but you **can** use primitive booleans in logging: `Log.d(TAG, "bool is " + bool);`

Answer (score 4):

Possibly need to call View.requestLayout() or View.forceLayout() on the buttons View to refresh the buttons state

Comment: You're my hero. Have been struggling with this error on 4.3 for several days

Answer (score 0):

Because the button's setChecked() method accepts a primitive `boolean` as parameter. you're supplying a `Boolean` (wrapper class) variable. Normally that should be fine, however it doesn't work on this specific method, so you might need to manually unbox the variable or change the type of mBool to `boolean`

Comment: If posting a answer that is already posted. vote up the earlier one instead posting a new one. And if have anything to add . post that as a comment. Thats how this community works. all folks need to run synchronously

Comment: I commented in code that i was only creating a Boolean (nonprimitive) because i wanted to use its toString() method for logging. The boolean I am using for setChecked() is primitive.

Comment: you can use (mBool+"") to print out mBool(primitive)'s value.

Comment: can you check your toggleButton's state after setting setChecked?