# Custom ToggleButton setChecked(..) issue

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

After setting toggle button to **checked state**, every time I click on it, its in same state.

**custom selector :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_icon" android:state_checked="true" 
    android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_icon" android:state_checked="true" 
    android:state_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/map_view_icon" android:state_checked="false" 
    android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/map_view_icon" android:state_checked="false" 
    android:state_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

**toggle button :**

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_map_or_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_selector"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/map_view_icon"            
        />
```

**java code :**

In button onClick listener, `isChecked` is always false

```
boolean isChecked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();      

Log.i(TAG, "isChecked : "+isChecked);
// **its always false and image also not changing.**
```

Please suggest whats wrong here.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025943/androids-togglebutton-setchecked-method-not-changing-status-of-button) answer, but no use.

**Edit :** I did a sample project with same scenario. Its working fine but in my project Fragment, its behaving differently.

Comment: You may have good reasons, but why aren't you using a ToggleButton? I can pass over some code that uses these views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_icon"
      android:state_checked="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/map_view_icon"
      android:state_checked="false" />
```

You've put a lot of conditions for the different states and that's what causing the problem (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) for more information).

Following your EDIT:

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_map_or_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_selector"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/selector_name"            
        />
```

This will fix it for you **FOR SURE**! You're using the map icon directly and never go through the selector.

Comment: I tried it before. Even for these simple states, once i set checked through java code, subsequent clicks on button neither changing image nor state is other than false.

Comment: Ok, then the question is how do you use the selector?

Comment: edited question. Please have a look it.

Comment: You cant use map_view_icon for icon and selector. This will show only the icon, not the selector.

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake in coding so it was not changing state.

Answer (score -1):

Selectors have an order (see [Drawable States](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)).

Remove the `android:button` attribute.
Set the Selector as background to your `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_map_or_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"/>
```

And the `custom_selector.xml` looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Checked and pressed -->
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_icon" />
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/map_view_icon" />
    <!-- Checked -->
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_icon" />
    <!-- Default (not checked) -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/map_view_icon"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Just rename your selector.xml and set it as background. Dont use the same name for the icon and the selector!